# How to initialize CKEditor textarea line breaks as like html textarea line breaks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor

1. HTML textareas can recognize line breaks (enter button) and i can save the element's text value into database. Then i can get those data, set it on any textarea, i still have line breaks (no problem until here).
2. CKEditor textarea puts `<p>` or `<br />` after line breaks. When i remove these tags, CKEditor cannot recognize there's a line break.

Purpose : I'm using a word counter plugin with CKEditor, so i need to use CKEditor as like a textarea. I need the plain text value.

I tried these so far :

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().getText()
```

Yes i can get the text value correctly, i put this value on DB, but when i reload my page, the line breaks are gone. Because ckeditor works only with html tags ?

```
config.autoParagraph = false;
```

This one just removes the `<p>` tag at the beginning of the content.

I need plain text+line breaks that's it. Any suggestions ? Or should i write down my own classes ?

Comment: Why do you use CKEditor if you only want plain text?

Comment: @AlfonsoML because i'm gonna have to upgrade it to the html later, and also for the char counter/limit.

Comment: Until you work with HTML, I would keep using a normal textarea and use a simpler script to provide the char counter (modern browsers themselves can take care of char limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.map
            .call(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().$.childNodes,
                 function(item){
                  return item.innerText;
                  })
            .join("\n");
```

Just a crazy answer to convert `<p>` blocks to a string separated by `\n`

Comment: gonna check that out and feedback. Thanks.